# frequency of a letter in a string using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

In this program I have been having trouble to get the terminal window I suspect it might be a runtime error .I am using blue J btw. Also I dont understand why the code used this

> **f[ch-'A']++;**

Please help out with  a tracing for this program.

This is the code:

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> public class frequency
> {
>     public static void main(String args[])
>     {
>         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
>        
>         int f[]= new int[26];
>         System.out.println("enter a string");
>         String input = sc.nextLine();
>         
>         input= input.toUpperCase();
>         
>         for(int i=0; i<input.length();i++)
>         {
>             char ch=input.charAt(i);
>             if (Character.isLetter(ch))
>             f[ch-'A']++;
>         }
>         System.out.println("Characters  Frequency");
>         for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
>         {
>             if( f[i]!=0)
>            {
>                System.out.println((char) (i+'A') + "\t\t" + f[i]);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: There is no error in this code maybe ... problem with the terminal

Comment: Can you share input which you are passing, there is no problem in code.  
Also `f[ch-'A']++;` is like `f[ch-'A'] = f[ch-'A']+1;`  i.e. increment value at that specific position.

Comment: @daksh I didn't get till the terminal the process kept loading on and on

Comment: @fungus ahh edit the question and add a screenshot of all the problems to it ...would it easier to understand

Comment: @fungus your code doesnt affect the IDE so...may be the terminal has been minimized to point or something ...try to open the terminal using shortcuts or the bluejs toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is converting the text to uppercase

```
input= input.toUpperCase();
```

each char can have the ascii value of `A` subtracted (see https://www.asciitable.com/) to obtain an index into the array.

```
'B' - 'A' == 1  etc
```

**test**

```
enter a string
stupid sod
Characters  Frequency
D       2
I       1
O       1
P       1
S       2
T       1
U       1
```

Comment: i still kinda am confused how the difference in the values of the character relates ...sry this is dumb

Comment: It is just maths, The value of a `B` is 66 and the value of `A` is 65.  These values are put into an array.  Arrays are index from 0, so `A` - `A` (65 - 65) gets put into element 0, `B` - `A` (66 - 65) gets put into element 1 etc.

Comment: oh i missed the part that they would be stored in positions as well ! thanks this clears it :)